# Getting Errors when Subclassing JSON (Swift)

Tags: json, swift, subclassing, jsondecoder

I'm fairly new to dealing with JSON data in Swift and I am trying to subclass some products. I don't mean to code dump, but I want to give you the whole picture. I have three errors that say the same thing: ***Errors thrown from here are not handled*** They occur in `required init`. Thanks in advance. Here's the code:

```
import UIKit

class Product: Decodable {
    var category: String = ""
    var material: String = ""

    init() {

    }
}

class TelephoneWithCord: Product {

    var sku: Double
    var isNew: Bool

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case sku = "sku"
        case isNew = "isNew"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.sku = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .sku)
        self.isNew = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isNew)
    }
}

let json = """

{
    "category" : "home",
    "material" : "plastic",
    "sku" : 264221,
    "isNew" : true
}

""".data(using: .utf8)!

let telephoneWithCord = try! JSONDecoder().decode(TelephoneWithCord.self, from: json)

telephoneWithCord.category
telephoneWithCord.material
telephoneWithCord.sku
telephoneWithCord.isNew
```

Comment: It should be `required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Errors thrown", could perhaps, be a hint on how to fix this. Add `throws` to `required init`. Also, don't forget to call `super` for your code to be properly initialized or you will get another error. Try these changes ...

```
required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {  // add throws to eliminate errors

    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.sku = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .sku)
    self.isNew = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isNew)
    try super.init(from: decoder)  // calling super for proper intialization of code
}
```

As a side note: If you are not using any decimal points in your sku's, then you should change the type to `Int` instead of `Double`.

Comment: y̶o̶u̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶t̶y̶p̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶I̶n̶t̶ ̶i̶n̶s̶t̶e̶a̶d̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶D̶o̶u̶b̶l̶e̶ You shouldn't use a numeric type for this at all. It's not a number, it's a series of digits.

Comment: @Caswell  Are you suggesting to represent it as a `String`?

Comment: I think that it is likely represented as an `Int` in the backend, so I would fell more comfortable keeping it that way. I could be wrong. JohnW would know for sure and he should adjust his code accordingly.

Comment: Also, if there are some sku's that do have decimals, then it may be wiser to keep all of them as `Doubles`. These are things that JohnW will need to determine.

Comment: The backend needs to be fixed too, then. I'm sure everyone will enjoy spending the time spent resolving this one: https://gist.github.com/woolsweater/f7c1ca8f0f1c3ea1152e38acc135c6f0

Comment: @Caswell Your saying what you think it shouldn’t be, but not saying what you think it should be. String type or something else?